# how to set testBuildType to active build variant automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

It seems that `testBuildType` is by default set to `debug`.
When we change the active build variant in android studio, Espresso tests won't work and we need to set `testBuildType = activeBuildVariant` manually in Gradle. As shown below.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        .....
    }

    testBuildType = "local"
}
```

Changing this manually is not convenient.

- Is there any way to automate this?
- How to get an active build variant?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No.. i gave up on that @Almighty

Answer (score 0):

I was trying that, but I could not do it, instead you can pass a property in any gradle task you want.

Add this in gradle.properties:

```
testBuildType=debug
```

Then in you android.defaultConfig block:

```
if (project.hasProperty("testBuildType")) {
    testBuildType project.property("testBuildType")
}
```

and you can call the tasks like:

```
./gradlew <task> -PtestBuildType="release"
```